Average area of the convex hull of the graph of a random permutation
Let $n \in \mathbb N$. For a permutation $\sigma$ in $S_n$, draw the graph of $\sigma$ i.e. the point set $\{(j, \sigma(j)) \,\, | \,\, j=1,2,\dots, n\}$ and form its convex hull. Call the area of the convex hull $A(\sigma)$.
For example when $\sigma = (2, 19, 20, 12, 16, 1, 10, 5, 18, 7, 13, 9, 15, 8, 17, 4, 3, 14, 11, 6)$ we have $A(\sigma) = \frac{553}{2}$.

By Pick's theorem $2A(\sigma) \in \mathbb Z$, so the function
$$
G_n(x) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} x^{2A(\sigma)}
$$
is a polynomial and the average of the area of a random permutation is given by $\frac{1}{2}G_n'(1)$. Can something be said about the asymptotic behaviour of this value as $n \to \infty$? How about the calculation of $G_n$ for a largish $n$?
Some sort of guess would be that the convex hull is almost a square when $n$ is large, so its area would be $n^2$.
For $n=1,2,\dots, 7$ I calculated the following.
The average areas: $0, 0, 1, \frac{41}{12}, \frac{437}{60}, \frac{4577}{360}, \frac{16591}{840}$
$$\begin{aligned}
G_1 &= 0 \\
G_2 &= 1 \\
G_3 &= 2 \\
G_4 &= 4x^{3} + 2 \\
G_5 &= 2 x^{10} + 14 \, x^{8} + 2 \, x^{6} + 4 \, x^{5} + 2 \\
G_6 &= 4 x^{34} + 36 x^{32} + 40 x^{31} + 18 x^{30} + 100 x^{29} + 116 x^{28} + 44 x^{27} + 56 x^{26} + 56 x^{25} + 64 x^{24} + 40 x^{23} + 16 x^{22} + 20 x^{21} + 20 x^{20} + 32 \, x^{19} + 4 x^{18} + 8 x^{17} + 16 x^{16} + 4 x^{15} + 10 x^{14} + 4 x^{13} + 6 x^{10} + 4 x^{9} + 2
\end{aligned}$$
And the roots of $G_7$ look like this:

I don't know if these have any significance, but one pair appears to be separated and others close to the unit circle (but isn't the closeness to unit circle like a general thing).

The area of the square that contains the points $(1,1), (1,n), (n,n), (n,1)$ is $(n-1)^2$ but the maximum area of your convex hull is less than that, I suspect no more than $(n-2)^2+1$ and this might be tight but unlikely if $n \ge 4$

Some simulations I made show that it seems to be slightly less than $(n-2)^2$ for n up to 15, but still quadratic. Is it at least $cn^2$ for some $c>0$? Would showing this be interesting?

Suppose we have a $kn$ points, with $k\geq 3$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We think of $k$ as fixed, and $n$ large. We give an asymptotic lower bound of $\frac{n^2}{k^2}-O(n)$ on the average area by providing a lower bound on $A(kn)$ for some special permutations. In the hopes of making the argument clear, I have not made any effort into optimizing it, and it is crude in multiple places. Perhaps this will inspire other answers that get closer to the truth (something like $(kn)^2-O(n)$ should be right).
We will say a permutation is special if the following four conditions hold:
\begin{align}
&\sigma(1) \in \{1,\dots, n\},\\ &\sigma(2)\in \{(k-1)n,\dots, kn\},\\&\sigma(kn-1) \in \{1,\dots, n\},\\ &\sigma(kn)\in \{(k-1)n,\dots, kn\}.
\end{align}
Note that there are $n^2(n-1)^2(kn-4)!$ special permutations. Furthermore, the convex hull of the corresponding points $(j, \sigma(j))$ contains a $(k-2)n$ by $(kn-4)$ rectangle, so $A(kn)\geq (k-2)n\cdot (kn-4)$. Thus, the contribution to the total area of special permutations is at least
$$
n^3(n-1)^2(kn-4)!(k-2) (kn-4).
$$
So the average area is at least
\begin{align}
\frac{n^3(n-1)^2(kn-4)!(k-2) (kn-4)}{(kn)!} &= \frac{n^3(n-1)^2(k-2) (kn-4)}{kn(kn-1)(kn-2)(kn-3)}\\
&\geq \frac{n^3(n-1)^2(k-2) (kn-4)}{k^4n^4}\\
&\geq \frac{(n-1)^2(k-2) (kn-4)}{k^4n}.
\end{align}
The numerator is of the form $k^2n^3-O(n^2)$, so asymptotically the average area is at least roughly $\frac{n^2}{k^2}$.
